# gson - long values of array become a float values

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I need to create json of this format:

```
{
  "array": [
    1482922777223,
    0.014221191,
    0.014221191,
    0.014221191
  ]
}
```

Data.class

```
public class Data {

   @SerializedName("array")
   @Expose
   private List<Float> array = null;
}
```

to convert object to JSON string i use gson library.

```
List<Float> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add((float)1482922777223);
list.add(0.014221191);
list.add(0.014221191);
list.add(0.014221191);
Data data = new Data(list);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(data);
```

Result string:

```
{
  "array": [
    1.4829219E12, <--- HOW TO GET HERE 1482922777223?
    0.014221191,
    0.014221191,
    0.014221191
  ]
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register `TypeAdapter` for `Float` values.

E.g:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();        
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Float.class,  new JsonSerializer<Float>() {
  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(final Float src, final Type typeOfSrc, final JsonSerializationContext context) {
      BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(src);    
      return new JsonPrimitive(value);
  }
});

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
String json = gson.toJson(data);
```

Output :

```
{
  "array": [
    1482922777223,
    0.014221191,
    0.014221191,
    0.014221191
  ]
}
```